# Symmetric Convolution using discrete cosine transform

Tags: fft, convolution

Can someone nicely give me one simple example of performing symmetric convolution using dct? 
e.g.

```
f[-2:3]=[1 2 3 2 1 5];  %f is symmetric about 0
g[0:3]=[8 9 6 2];
```

I think one fastest way to perform linear convolution `h=f*g` is using DCT.
If one use traditional `DFT` one need to do zero padding.

Comment: did you get any example of doing linear convolution using dct? I am looking for convolution on images using dct